# I need to display text with system generated value i.e alphanumeric value.and insert into sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 4 locations Chennai, Banglore, Hyderabad, Mumbai.

Depending on user selection from dropdown, I need to gennerate an id like this:

```
If they select Chennai - CHE001,CH002,CHE002,CHE003,CHE004.....etc
If they select Mumbai - MUM001,MUM002,MUM003,MUM004.......etc
If they select Hyderabad - HYD001,HYD002,HYD003,HYD004........etc
```

like that in database it has to save
Like that auto generated id as has to save in database but it must be in unique.... I don't how it will work with SQL functions are stored procedure, asp.net .. please kindly help for this issue.

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create stored procedure similar to below:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @CITY VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MUMBAI'
DECLARE @CITYCODE VARCHAR(3) = SUBSTRING(@CITY,1,3)

INSERT INTO TBL (ID)
SELECT @CITYCODE + RIGHT('000' + CAST((CAST(REPLACE(ISNULL(MAX(ID),@CITYCODE + '000'),@CITYCODE,'') AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR),3)
FROM TBL
WHERE ID LIKE @CITYCODE + '%'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Selected varchar(100)='Chennai'

Select Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +ID  
 From (Select Top 999 ID=Upper(Left(@Selected,3))+Format(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)),'000') From master..spt_values ) A
 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
 CHE001,CHE002,CHE003,CHE004,CHE005,CHE006,CHE007,CHE008,CHE009,CHE010,{...},CHE997,CHE998,CHE999
```

Or if you need rows

```
Declare @Selected varchar(100)='Chennai'

Select Top 999 ID=Upper(Left(@Selected,3))+Format(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)),'000') From master..spt_values
```

Returns

```
ID
CHE001
CHE002
CHE003
CHE004
CHE005
{...}
CHE997
CHE998
CHE999
```

Comment: @srisanjeev123 Always happy to help.

Comment: @srisanjeev123  This is a little dated :)   That said, if you find an answer to be helpful, be sure to ACCEPT it